# Configurable Product Attribute Price "undefined"

Tags: attributes, configurable-product, price, product-page

Using a **configurable product** and the **size attribute** to change the **prices** at the **product page** the size selector don't show the full price and show this "undefined" 
Front-end
https://prnt.sc/j9mkqc 
Admin Panel:
http://prntscr.com/j9mpb5